# Apply fixed size repeating texture to different sized walls

Tags: texturing, materials, uv

I am new to Blender.
I made a cube with the texture I wanted, see image attached. The texture is an image that is repeating itself.

[image: Cube with the look I have]

What I would like is:

- to apply the same texture on the cube to walls that have different sizes;
- to apply the same texture on the cube to curved walls that have different sizes.

The best would be that the cube's texture is a reference for the walls' texture. This way, if I change my mind, changing the cube's texture will change all the walls' texture automatically with the new one.

Thank you for your help

Comment: do you mean that you want to keep the same size for the pattern whatever is the object?

Comment: Well, the main thing here is: these tiling textures do not really work with procedural texture coordinates like _General_ or _Object_, you need UV maps for them. So at first you need them correctly unwrapped to display the texture as you want. Then you can enable _Transform_ > _Correct Face Attributes_ in the viewport options so that moving or extruding faces keeps the tiling scale etc., but this only works well if to change the faces parallel to the UV alignment, which will cause a problem if you are going to bend walls...

Answer (score 0):

To link a material to one or more objects, just select it from the dropdown menu left to the **+New** button in the shader editor.

[image]

As Gordon already stated in his comment, the texture projection depends on the mesh shape, so you will need to UV unwrap your walls (especially the curved one) and use the UV map as texture coordinates:

[image]

Also, you can try to get away with Texture Coordinate > Object, so every object will have the exact same texture size. But you need to make sure that all your mesh objects have a global scale of 1 (you can apply after transforming):

[image]

**Note:** This will only work well for straight (or maybe only slightly curved) walls.